# How to restrict which nodes produce output in stylesheet

Tags: templates, xslt, match

I am working on a transform.  The goal is to transform nodes into key/value pairs.  Found a great stylesheet recommendation on this forum but I could use some help to tweak it a bit.  For any node that has no children, the node name should become the value of `<name>` and the value should become the value of `<value>`.  The source document may have some hierarchical structure to it, but I want to ignore that and only return the bottom nodes, transformed of course.

Here is my source data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <objects>
     <Technical_Spec__c>
      <Id>a0e30000000vFmbAAE</Id>
      <F247__c>4.0</F247__c>
      <F248__c xsi:nil="true"/>
      <F273__c>Bronx</F273__c>
...
     </Technical_Spec__c>
   </objects>
```

Here is the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">   
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[count(*) = 0]">   
<item>
    <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
    </name>
    <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </value>
</item>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[count(*) > 0]">  
    <items>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>             
    </items>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT - The stylesheet should transform these nodes to key value pairs like this:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <name>F247__c</name>
    <value>4.0</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>F248__c</name>
    <value></value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>F273__c</name>
    <value>Bronx</value>
  </item>
...
</items>
```

CURRENT OUTPUT - But it creates nested 'items' elements like this:

```
<items>
  <items>
    <item><name></name><value></value></item>
...
   </items>
</items>
```

I understand (I think) that it is matching all the parent nodes including the top node 'objects' and nesting the 'matches count 0' template. So I tried altering the matches attribute to exclude 'objects' and start at 'Technical_Spec__c' like this (just the template lines):

```
 <xsl:template match="objects/Technical_Spec__c/*">
 <xsl:template match="*[count(*) = 0]">
 <xsl:template match="objects/*[count(*) > 0]">
```

In my mind this says "First (master) template only matches nodes with parents 'objects/Tech_Spec'. Second (inner) template matches any node with no children.  Third (outer) template matches nodes with parent 'objects' " - which should limit me to one .

OUTPUT AFTER ALTERING MATCH - Here is what I get:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
- <items xmlns=""><?xml version="1.0"?>
    <item><name>Id</name><value>a0e30000000vFmbAAE</value></item>
    <item><name>F247__c</name><value>4.0</value></item>
...
</items>
```

The extra `<items>` block is gone but there is an extra `<?xml>` block stuck in the middle so it's not recognized as valid xml anymore.

Any ideas?  Why the extra `<?xml>`;  How to restrict template to particular parts of the tree?

Comment: Please, provide in the question the exact output you want to produce and the exact rules what elements to process and what elements not to process. As to the XML declaration inside the output, this smells of a buggy XSLT processor, or could be the result of concatenating the outputs of two separate transformations, which you could have done  (and not noticed) accidentally.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre.  I added some (hopefully) clarifying remarks above. I will open a case with the vendor to see if there is a problem with the XSLT processor that they know of.  In looking at my stylesheet, do you think there is a concatenation of outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a great deal of trial and error, I stumbled on the following solution: I added a root anchor to the third template match criteria.

Instead of `match="*[count(*) > 0]"`, I now have `/*[count(*) > 0]`. This appears to eliminate the outer `<items>` element.  If anyone can tell me why, I'd appreciate it.  Why would this be different than `/objects/*[count(*) > 0]` ?

I do think Dimitre is right about the processor (which is IBM Cast Iron) so I did open a ticket.  I tested the same stylesheet from above on an online XSLT tester and did not get the extra `<?xml ?>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">   
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[count(*) = 0]">   
    <item>
    <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
    </name>
    <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </value>
</item>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/*[count(*) > 0]">  

    <items>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>             
    </items>
```